# Why does setting LayoutDirection on a LinearLayout not take effect immediately?

Tags: android

I am working on an application, using API 17 (4.2). In the application I am designing a layout class, and I would like to configure it according to the layout direction. However, I haven't been successful in retrieving the applied layout direction within the class:

```
LinearLayout layout = newLayout(context);
layout.setLayoutDirection(LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
int ld = layout.getLayoutDirection();    // STILL 0! I was expecting 1
```

My question is, how do I configure a layouts direction, and retrieve it within the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application 
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    >
```

As View checks RTL support first, if true, then resolve layout direction.

You can get more details in `View.resolveLayoutDirection()`.